# Unable to copy file to designated path before its deletion through RecursiveFileObserver

Tags: java, android, delete-file, fileobserver, notificationlistenerservice

FileObserverService.java

```
package com.example.statussaver.Utils;


import static android.os.FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;
import static android.os.FileObserver.DELETE;
import static android.os.FileObserver.DELETE_SELF;
import static android.os.FileObserver.MOVED_FROM;
import static android.os.FileObserver.MOVED_TO;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.example.statussaver.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class FileObserverService extends NotificationListenerService {
    private RecursiveFileObserver fileObserver;
    private String targetDirectory;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupFileObserver();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    String TAG = "de_ser";

    private void setupFileObserver() {
        targetDirectory = Consts.CPY_FILES_DIR;

        fileObserver = new RecursiveFileObserver(Consts.WHATSAPP_DIRECTORY, new RecursiveFileObserver.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, File file) {
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.e("file_chk", "File: " + file);
                } else {
                    Log.e("file_chk", "File not found");
                }
                switch (event) {
                    case DELETE: {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: DELETE " + file.exists());
                        handleFileDelete(file);
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        fileObserver.startWatching();
            }

    private void handleFileDelete(File deletedFile) {
        File fileDirectory = new File(Consts.CPY_FILES_DIR);
        if (!fileDirectory.exists()) {
            fileDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        if (deletedFile.exists()) {
            try {
                String fileName = deletedFile.getName();

                File destDirectory;
                if (fileName.contains(".mp4")) {
                    destDirectory = new File(Consts.VID_FILE_DIR);
                } else if (fileName.contains(".jpg") || fileName.contains(".jpeg") || fileName.contains(".png") || fileName.contains(".webp")) {
                    destDirectory = new File(Consts.IMG_FILE_DIR);
                } else if (fileName.contains(".aac") || fileName.contains(".mp3")) {
                    destDirectory = new File(Consts.AUD_FILE_DIR);
                } else if (fileName.contains(".opus") || fileName.contains(".ogg")) {
                    destDirectory = new File(Consts.VOICE_FILE_DIR);
                } else {
                    destDirectory = new File(Consts.DOC_FILE_DIR);
                }

                if (!destDirectory.exists()) {
                    destDirectory.mkdirs();
                }

                File destFile = new File(destDirectory, fileName);

                // Copy the file before deletion
                copyFile(deletedFile, destFile);

                // Now you can delete the file
                boolean isDeleted = deletedFile.delete();
                if (isDeleted) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "File deleted: " + deletedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to delete file: " + deletedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error copying file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "File does not exist anymore: " + deletedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

            private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {

                try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                     FileChannel source = fis.getChannel();
                     FileChannel destination = fos.getChannel()) {
                    destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                }
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(destFile));
                sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }

    }
```

RecursiveFileObserver.java

```
package com.example.statussaver.Utils;

import android.os.FileObserver;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

public class RecursiveFileObserver extends FileObserver{

    private final Map<String, FileObserver> mObservers = new HashMap<>();

    private String mPath;

    private int mMask;

    private EventListener mListener;

    public interface EventListener {
        void onEvent(int event, File file);
    }

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path, EventListener listener) {
        this(path, ALL_EVENTS, listener);
    }

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path, int mask, EventListener listener) {
        super(path, mask);
        mPath = path;
        mMask = mask | FileObserver.CREATE | FileObserver.DELETE_SELF;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    private void startWatching(String path) {
        synchronized (mObservers) {
            FileObserver observer = mObservers.remove(path);
            if (observer != null) {
                observer.stopWatching();
            }
            observer = new SingleFileObserver(path, mMask);
            observer.startWatching();
            mObservers.put(path, observer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startWatching() {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(mPath);

        // Recursively watch all child directories
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            String parent = stack.pop();
            startWatching(parent);

            File path = new File(parent);
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (watch(file)) {
                        stack.push(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean watch(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().equals(".") && !file.getName().equals("..");
    }

    private void stopWatching(String path) {
        synchronized (mObservers) {
            FileObserver observer = mObservers.remove(path);
            if (observer != null) {
                observer.stopWatching();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopWatching() {
        synchronized (mObservers) {
            for (FileObserver observer : mObservers.values()) {
                observer.stopWatching();
            }
            mObservers.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        File file;
        if (path == null) {
            file = new File(mPath);
        } else {
            file = new File(mPath, path);
        }
        notify(event, file);
    }

    private void notify(int event, File file) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onEvent(event & FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS, file);
        }
    }

    private class SingleFileObserver extends FileObserver {
        private String filePath;

        public SingleFileObserver(String path, int mask) {
            super(path, mask);
            filePath = path;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            File file;
            if (path == null) {
                file = new File(filePath);
            } else {
                file = new File(filePath, path);
            }

            switch (event & FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS) {
                case DELETE_SELF:
                    RecursiveFileObserver.this.stopWatching(filePath);
                    break;
                case CREATE:
                    if (watch(file)) {
                        RecursiveFileObserver.this.startWatching(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                    break;
            }

            RecursiveFileObserver.this.notify(event, file);
        }
    }
}
```

Consts.java

```
package com.example.statussaver.Utils;

import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;

public class Consts {
    public static final File STATUS_DIRECTORY = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses");
 public static final String WHATSAPP_DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "WhatsApp/Media";
 public static final String WHATSAPP_IMG_DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Pictures";

    public static final File STATUS_DIRECTORY_BUSINESS = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "WhatsApp Business/Media/.Statuses");

    public static final String APP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "StatusSaverDir";
    public static final String CPY_FILES_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "WhatsWebCpyFiles";
    public static final String VID_FILE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Videos";
    public static final String IMG_FILE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Images";
    public static final String AUD_FILE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Audios";
    public static final String DOC_FILE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Documents";
    public static final String VOICE_FILE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Voices";
    public static final String APP_DIR_BUSINESS = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "BusinessStatusSaverDir";

    public static final File APP_DIR_SAVED = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "StatusSaverDir");

    public static final int THUMBSIZE = 128;
}
```

I am trying to copy file to a designated path when Delete event is triggered, but the file is being deleted before copy. I have tried to delay the delete event as well but it is not working. I want to copy the file that is being deleted to the designated first, and then execute the deletion process

Comment: The file observer tells you that a file has been deleted. It will not exist any more when you get that message. You have a lot of exists() checks but you are not telling us if one of them comes true.

Comment: `I want to copy the file that is being deleted` It is not being deleted. It has been deleted already. Well that is how i see it. Tell us if it is different.

Comment: `and then execute the deletion process` Who is executing that process?

Comment: @blackapps then how to proceed to copy files to designated path before deletion?

Comment: You still did not tell us what exists() returned in `if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.e("file_chk", "File: " + file);
                } else {
                    Log.e("file_chk", "File not found");
                }`

Comment: And that code should return when the file does not exist: `if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.e("file_chk", "File: " + file);
                } else {
                    Log.e("file_chk", "File not found"); Toast(..file does not exist...); return;
                }`

Comment: @blackapps if(file.exists()) is returning false

Comment: Why didn't you that tell in your post as problem description? And why did you use code that tries to handle an already deleted and hence non existing file? You should stop then as i suggested earlier.